# Filtering results in populated field mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm not exactly a back end developer, so I'm going to try to keep it simple.

I currently have 2 Schemas:

In Offer.js:

```js
new Schema({
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['OPEN', 'FINISHED', 'INACTIVE'],
    default: 'OPEN',
  },
  externalOfferId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  origin: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Location',
    autopopulate: true,
  },
  destination: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Location',
    autopopulate: true,
  },
});
```

in Location.js:

```js
new Schema({
  // Other properties...
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'AM',
      'BA',
      // All the brazilian states...
      'SP',
      'SE',
    ],
    required: true,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
```

Since our location is just a reference on the offer object, i can't `.find({'origin.state': myStateValue})`. How do i filter out by that without fetching all the entries on `offers`?

Also, I don't know if it interferes in something but I'm doing it at my GraphQL resolvers.

Comment: Is origin unique for all documents across Offer collection ?

Comment: Hmmmm, not really, since we can make different offers for the same location... Should it be?